# mysqldump doesn't work in crontab

Tags: mysql, cron

I'm trying to add a cronjob in the crontab (ubuntu server) that backups the mysql db.

Executing the script in the terminal as root works well, but inserted in the crontab nothing happens. I've tried to run it each minutes but no files appears in the folder /var/db_backups.

(Other cronjobs work well)

Here is the cronjob:

> * * * * * mysqldump -u root -pHERE THERE IS MY PASSWORD
>   --all-databases | gzip > /var/db_backups/database_`date +%d%m%y`.sql.gz

what can be the problem?

Comment: What if you use full path for `mysqldump` and `gzip`?

Comment: Do you intend this job to run every minute?

Comment: @fedorqui i've tried using: /usr/bin/mysqldump /usr/local/gnu/gzip but it's the same.

Comment: @JaneAvriette definitely no. i'm just trying running it each minutes for testing purposes

Comment: Does your password have any special characters like `#` `$` etc?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 116):

You need to escape % character with \

```
mysqldump -u 'username' -p'password' DBNAME > /home/eric/db_backup/liveDB_`date +\%Y\%m\%d_\%H\%M`.sql
```

Comment: I would like to vote +10! No other source than this (many Google results, websites, forum posts) have given me this result, this was the solution for me. Without this answer, I would have searched for hours...

Comment: one mistake I made was to leave a space between -p and my password, there should be no space i.e -pPASSWORD

Comment: @Basj: what if I searched for hours until I found this answer? *mind blown*

Comment: Very useful your answer. Thanks so much. After to escape % character with \ , it works fine. Thanks @Sandeep

Comment: This was my problem as well; if you follow one of the first Google links about "Backing up MySQL on Centos", they do not include the \

Comment: putting date inside quotes also works - `date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M"`

Comment: What's the reason for this? What does % mean for crontab?

Comment: @Manny265 but if password contains special character it should be `-p'P@ssword#'`

Answer (score 9):

I was trying the same but I found that dump was created with 0KB. Hence, I got to know about the solution which saved my time.

Command :

```
0 0 * * * mysqldump -u 'USERNAME' -p'PASSWORD' DATEBASE > /root/liveDB_`date +\%Y\%m\%d_\%H\%M\%S`.sql
```

**NOTE:**
1) You can change the time setting as per your requirement. I have set every day in above command.

2) Make sure you enter your USERNAME, PASSWORD, and DATABASE inside single quote (').

3) Write down above command in Crontab.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 6):

Check cron logs (should be in /var/log/syslog) You can use grep to filter them out.

> grep CRON /var/log/syslog

Also you can check your local mail box to see if there are any cron mails

> /var/mail/username

You can also set up other receiving mail in you crontab file

> MAILTO=your@mail.com

Comment: I tried grep CRON and it gave me: CMD (/usr/bin/mysqldump -u root -pPASSWORD! --all-databases | gzip > /var/db_backups/database_... so the command is executed but not produces output files

Comment: Did you set up cron for root or for other user? Maybe your cron user has no rights to execute mysqldump

Comment: I haven't setuppet nothing yet. Just used crontab -e on a blank ubuntu server.
How can i setup that option? Thanks

Comment: Try to dump as regular user and see if it works, check writing permissions for /var/db_backups/ and executing permissions for /usr/bin/mysqldump http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod

Comment: you're right. as user i get:
-bash: /var/db_backups/database_011113.sql.gz: Permission denied

Comment: Try sudo chmod 777 /var/db_backups and then check or set up cron as root

Comment: How can i setup cron as root?

Comment: I tried both sudo crontab -e and chmod 777 /var/db_backups. Now if i execute the command as user it works but cron still not working

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you can create a custom command **mycommand**. To which you can add more options. You must give execute permissions.

It is preferable to have a folder where they store all your backups, in this case using a writable folder "backup" which first create in "your home" for example.

**My command** in "usr/local/bin/mycommand":

```
#!/bin/bash
MY_USER="your_user"
MY_PASSWORD="your_pass"
MY_HOME="your_home"
case $1 in 
"backupall")
    cd $MY_HOME/backup
    mysqldump --opt --password=$MY_PASSWORD --user=$MY_USER  --all-databases > bckp_all_$(date +%d%m%y).sql
    tar -zcvf bckp_all_$(date +%d%m%y).tgz bckp_all_$(date +%d%m%y).sql
    rm bckp_all_$(date +%d%m%y).sql;;
*)  echo "Others";;
esac
```

**Cron:** Runs the 1st day of each month.

```
0 0 1 * * /usr/local/bin/mycommand backupall
```

I hope it helps somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I had a similar problem and was able to get it fixed.

In your case you could insert that mysqldump command to a script 
then source the profile of the user who is executing the mysqldump command 
for eg:

```
. /home/bla/.bash_profile
```

then use the absolute path of the mysqldump command

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump -u root -pHERE THERE IS MY PASSWORD --all-databases | gzip > /var/db_backups/database_`date +%d%m%y`.sql.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

Local Host mysql Backup:
0 1 * * * /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump -uroot -ppassword --opt database > /path/to/directory/filename.sql

(There is no space between the -p and password or -u and username - replace root with a correct database username.)

It works for me. no space between the -p and password or -u and username

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file and exec the code there to dump into a file location and zip it . Run that script via a cron

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Percona Server](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-server) (a MySQL fork) on Ubuntu. The package (very likely the regular MySQL package as well) comes with a maintenance account called `debian-sys-maint`. In order for this account to be used,  the credentials are created when installing the package; and they are stored in `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`.

And now the surprise: A symlink `/root/.my.cnf` pointing to `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf` gets installed as well.

This file is [an option file](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html) read automatically when using `mysql` or `mysqldump`. So basically you then had login credentials given twice - in that file and on command line. This was the problem I had.

So one solution to avoid this condition is to use [`--no-defaults`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-defaults) option for `mysqldump`. The option file then won't be read. However, you provide credentials via command line, so anyone who can issue a `ps` can actually see the password once the backup runs. So it's best if you create an own option file with user name and password and pass this to `mysqldump` via [`--defaults-file`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_defaults-file).

You can create the option file by using [`mysql_config_editor`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-config-editor.html) or simply in any editor.

Running `mysqldump` via `sudo` from the command line as `root` works, just because `sudo` usually does not change `$HOME`, so `.my.cnf` is not found then. When running as a cronjob, it is.

Answer (score -5):

You might also need to restart the service to load any of your changes.

```
service cron restart
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/cron restart
```

Comment: when you `crontab -e` and `save`, cron will install new crontab automatically, restart is not needed

Comment: restarting `crontab` is not required and is actually misleading for the issue mentioned above